# How to parse this table in jsoup android java

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I want to parse the date 05.03.2019 and the Fizyka 1A in the html below, but I can't make it work. Can you help me to get this data parsed by jsoup?

```html
<tbody class="text-center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>04.03.2019</div>
      <div>-</div>
    </td>
  <td>
    <div>05.03.2019</div>
    <div>
      <span class="blockElement">
        <a title="Zobacz więcej informacji o sprawdzianie"
           href="/lebork/028323/Sprawdziany.mvc/Terminarz?
           data=636872544000000000&amp;rodzajWidoku=2">
          <b>Fizyka 1A</b>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>06.03.2019</div>
    <div>-</div>
  </td>
  <td>
 <div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you already tried? Did you run into a specific problem causing you to post here? Please remember Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service. We expect some effort on your part.

Comment: I tried something like this Elements links = doc.select("span.blockElement");

Comment: Element links = doc.select("td>b").first(); this also does not work

Answer (score 0):

Getting the first `b` which is anywhere inside `span.blockElement`. You could also use `"span.blockElement>a>b"`. Your example `"td>b"` was searching for `b` which is direct child of `td`, but there's no `b` directly in `td`.

```
Element element = doc.select("span.blockElement b").first();
String name = element.text(); //Fizyka 1A
```

As the `div` with date doesn't have any `class` or `id` it's best to start with the result of previous selection `element` and then go few parents up and select the first `div`

```
Element dateElement = element.parent().parent().parent().parent().select("div").first();
String date = dateElement .text(); //05.03.2019
```